# celery 3.0.12 typeerror :run() got multiple values for values for keyword argument 'detach'

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, kombu

I want to run the periodic tasks using celery and celerybeat.am using 
celery 3.0.12 django-celery 3.0.11 kombu 2.5.3 and billiard 2.7.3.19 python 2.6 django 1.4.2. Can anyone please tell where its going wrong or missing any configuration part?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443,    in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382,  in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_celery-3.0.11-py2.6.egg/djcelery/management/base.py", line 74, in run_from_argv
return super(CeleryCommand, self).run_from_argv(argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_celery-3.0.11-py2.6.egg/djcelery/management/base.py", line 67, in execute
super(CeleryCommand, self).execute(*args, **options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_celery-3.0.11-py2.6.egg/djcelery/management/commands/celerybeat.py", line 24, in handle
beat.run(*args, **options)
TypeError: run() got multiple values for keyword argument 'detach'
```

TIA:)

update:
    task.py

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
import celery
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour='*', minute='10', day_of_week='*'))
def spam_task():
    """
    am fetching the user's spam and sending mail to spam users
    using django EmailMultiAlternatives
    """
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour='*', minute='10', day_of_week='*'))
def notify():
    """
    fetching the activities and notifying to users by sending mail
    """
```

settings.py

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("myapp.tasks", )
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'America/Chicago'
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_URL = 'django://'

BROKER_HOST = 'localhost'
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = 'guest'
BROKER_PASSWORD = 'guest'
BROKER_VHOST = '/' 

CELERY_EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
CELERY_EMAIL_TASK_CONFIG = {
     'queue' : 'email',
     'rate_limit' : '10/m',
     'name': 'djcelery_email_send',
     'ignore_result': True  }
```

Comment: Can you post your code, or at least relevant parts of it?

Comment: i have updated code..thanks for fast reply:)